# Different results between running inside Visual Studio and outside

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have written a quick C++ DLL in Visual Studio, with a single function called ReportVersion() that returns 1.

```
int _stdcall ReportVersion() {
    return 1;
}
```

I then created a VB.net EXE to call this DLL.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function ReportVersion Lib "Test_DLL.dll" () As Long

    Private Sub btnVersion_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVersion.Click
        Call MsgBox(ReportVersion())
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I press F5 and run in either Release/Debug mode, the return value of ReportVersion is 6824607285638070273.

If I build the solution and run the .EXE manually, the return value is 1 (as expected).

Where on earth is it getting 6824607285638070273 from?

For reference, I used these 2 articles as examples for creating them

http://edais.mvps.org/Tutorials/CDLL/CDLLch1b.html

http://edais.mvps.org/Tutorials/CDLL/CDLLch2.html

As I've never done a call between DLL/Application written in different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having emailed the original author of the linked articles, I was pleasantly surprised to get a response back about such an old article. This helped me understand the problem.

> In VB6, the "Integer" type was a signed 16-bit integer, and the "Long"
> type was a signed 32-bit integer.
>
> In VB.NET, the "Integer" type is a
> signed 32-bit integer, and the "Long" type is a 64-bit signed integer.
> The "Short" type was also added to fill the 16-bit signed integer
> role.
>
> Indeed, if you convert the value given back to you by ReportVersion()
> above you'll see it comes out to 0x5EB5E02B00000001.  As you can see
> the low 8 digits (0x00000001) have the correct value in, where as the
> high digits just have whatever data happened to be in memory next to
> it at the time.
>
> As for the discrepancy between running as an executable as opposed to
> within the IDE, I can only imagine that perhaps that area of memory is
> being cleared out prior to the application running so it actually
> returns 0x0000000000000001 which is correctly evaluated as 1.