# different results in IDE when setting word cell to bold

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop

We have a report application that fills a word template from information from our database, prior to sending it to clients etc.. The rest of the application runs with no problem but when I try and set table cells to bold it behaves differently in the VS IDE than when I run it externally.

I have tried different variations of the code below, but no matter what I do when I run this in the VS IDE  it successfully sets the appropriate table cells to bold, but if I run it outside of the IDE the table cells are not bolded.

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application = Nothing
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = Nothing
Dim Table0 As Word.Table = Nothing


Private Sub SetBold(ByRef currentTable As Word.Table, ByVal Col1Bold As Boolean, ByVal Row1Bold As Boolean)
    With currentTable
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
            For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
                .Cell(r, c).Range.Font.Bold = If(c = 1 And Col1Bold = True, True, If(r = 1 And Row1Bold = True, True, False))
            Next
        Next
    End With

    End Sub
```

This article is talking about something similar ([Different results between running inside Visual Studio and outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213618/different-results-between-running-inside-visual-studio-and-outside)), but I have not been able to use it to resolve my problem.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, the rest of the application runs with no problem at all.

Comment: So it runs differently depending on whether you run from within the IDE (debug mode) and as a standalone EXE?

Comment: This looks strange: .Cell(r, c).Range.Font.Bold = If(c = 1 And Col1Bold = True, True, If(r = 1 And Row1Bold = True, True, False)), why dont you try smth like: Dim setBold As Boolean
                setBold = (c = 1 And Col1Bold = True) Or (r = 1 And Row1Bold)
                If setBold Then
                    .Cell(r, c).Range.Font.Bold = True
                End If

Comment: thanks for your response tinamou, I have just tried that and unfortunately the behaviour is still the same: in the IDE it works, but as an exe it does not

Comment: I have just realised that it only works when I _step through_ the code, if I run the code but in the IDE without breakpoints it does not work. So that must be a timing issue?  I am going to insert some `system.threading.thread.sleep(n)` see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the issue, but I have found out that placing system.threading.thread.sleep(250) before the bold assignment fixes the problem. So it looks like it is something to do with timing and threads.